# How to create conditional checkboxes that hide each other?

Tags: webforms

I have 2 check-boxes.

- Checkbox 1: Attend event for 1 day
- Checkbox 2: Attend event for 2 days

If a checkbox is selected, I want to hide the other one. I don't want the user to be able to select both. If I create 2 rules, I get a *circular reference* error which breaks the form.

How do I achieve what I described?

Comment: There are some modules that do this on drupal.org for various versions of Drupal.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution: Don't use 2 fields with checkboxes, use one field with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need 2 checkboxes instead of a radio button, do the following: example with 2 checkboxes (Day1 and Day2).

[image]

For checkbox Day1 chose the following under Edit-Conditions

[image]

For checkbox Day2 do the same just vice versa.